# manipulating tag using java script

Tags: javascript

I am fairy new in learning JavaScript , I am practising to manipulate a tag, 
here is my code 
I know that I am making a silly mistake here but I am not sure which part has went wrong ?
could any one please give me some hint ?

```
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title>
        HTML Hyperlinks
    </title>    

</head>
<body>

<h1>
    HTML Hyperlinks
</h1>
<p>
    Here is a link to <a name = "hyper" href="http://yahoo.com/">page</a>.
    The text around the link is not part of the link. 
</p>
<script>
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var attribute = element.getAttribute("href");
        element.setAttribute("href","Http://google.com");
        element.setAttribute("target","_blank");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whenever you see a method with plural, as in `getElements...` and not `getElement...`, it gets more than one element, and you have a nodeList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

`var attribute = element.getAttribute("href");`

to this

`var attribute = element[0].getAttribute("href");`

Comment: actually your hint was good, but instead I did element[0].setAttribute("href","Http://google.com");
element[0].setAttribute("target","_blank");

Comment: @saharsadatjafari Ok. Just be sure to accept an answer (whichever one helped the most) by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` says elements. Plural.

It returns a NodeList, which is like an Array, not a single Element.

You need to loop over its return value (e.g. with `for`) or access it by index (`[0]`)

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting a collection of a tags, but then treating them like a single entity.

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var attribute = element.getAttribute("href");
    element.setAttribute("href","Http://google.com");
    element.setAttribute("target","_blank");
</script>
```

try this

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    var attribute = element.getAttribute("href");
    element.setAttribute("href","Http://google.com");
    element.setAttribute("target","_blank");
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
     {
          var element = elemenets[i];
          var attribute = element.getAttribute("href");
          element.setAttribute("href","Http://google.com");
          element.setAttribute("target","_blank");
        }

</script>
```